# C# Сборка для смешанного режима - что за ошибка, как исправить?

Tags: c#, sqlite, компиляция, sqlite3, runtime

Есть библиотека классов, в которую установлен SQLite. Получаю ошибку - понятия не имею что это такое и не получается загуглить :(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, где это поставлена версия 2.0, в свойствах проекта установлена 4.5.1

На всякий случай код метода db.Add

```
public void Add(Message message)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=D:\\messages.sqlite, version=3"))
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "insert into messages (name), values (" + message.JsonMessage + ")";
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Версия 2.0 поставлена в свойствах библиотеки SQLite. Найдите свежую версию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй добавь в app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Спасибо, у меня три проекта. Клиент, сервер, библиотека. Сервер использует библиотеку. Написал ваш код в библиотеку. В каждого из проектов поставил версию .net 2.0, затем обратно. Когда выставляешь версию перезагружается проект. Не знаю, что конкретно помогло. ПС. dll, которые используются в библиотеке должны лежать в bin сервера и App.Config во время работы сервера для библиотеки тоже читается оттуда.